# How do I use and show a vocabulary with multiple fields?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

When I create a new vocabulary, I can create it in such a way that there are multiple fields. However, when I then create a content type with a field a term reference to that vocabulary, I only can see the name field from the vocabulary and not the other fields.

This regardless of the method I use, whether be radio buttons, check list, select list, autocomplete, autocomplete deluxe. I want to show those other fields so I can discriminate between two very similar, but with distinct values in the vocabulary.

For example, if it is a vocabulary of names, to add a date of birth which gets at least shown (and preferably is editable when adding a new term using autocomplete deluxe) when I fill in the form when adding an item of that content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).  This will let you create a taxonomy term field on your content type and give you the option to render the entire term using the display of your choice (teaser, full etc).

Setting it up would be very similar to what you've already tried with term reference:

1. Create an entity reference field in your content type
2. Target type = taxonomy term
3. Set target bundle if preferred, then save
4. Under manage display, set the field format to rendered entity
5. Set the view mode to your preferred option (you would configure these options under your vocabulary manage display screen)

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules, create a new View and <kbd>Add</kbd> an Entity Reference Display:

[image]

Then add in the fields the Term Name and the Term ID (this is just an example, you can add more fields), click in the Term ID and check Exclude from display,

[image]

Save and click in the Term Name and go to rewrite the output of the title as `[name] - ([tid])`

[image]

Go to edit the settings of the format and check the Term Name, this will allow you to search by the Name of the Term.

[image]

Save the view.

Go to edit your Entity Reference field and select in the Mode Views: .... (like the following image) and select your View (in this case the name is: etiquetas - Entity Reference) and save the settings:

[image]

Then go to see the result when you go to add a new node:

[image]

Comment: This is very thorough, but misses the first point of having an entity reference field. Therefore I accepted the other answer, sorry.

Comment: @Ernst the field is an Entity Reference field, but to a Taxonomy Term, this is not what you need?

Comment: @Ernst in the last Picture, the field Articulo, is an Entity Reference field to a Taxonomy Term